# AEM template logic not recognized by iText while generating PDF

Tags: javascript, itext, pdf-generation, aem, itext7

I have a PDF template, where complete address is one of the section. Each address line is a text form field like Address Line 1, Address Line 2, City ,State and Zip. For my requirement, if address line 2 is empty, city, state and zip fields should move up. I am unable to have that logic working using iText.

I created the template using AEM designer and it has Javascript logic to make fields hidden and it will automatically move below fields up if any of the fields in that section are hidden like this

`if((this.rawValue == null) || (this.rawValue == "")) { this.presence =  "hidden"; }`

iText failed to recognize this code while creating PDF file. Instead I tried having code in itext to achieve this. I am able to hide the fields if I use below

`form.getField(     "Correspondence[0].Page1[0].FooterContent[0].TemplateContent1[0].AddressBox[0].ADDLINE2[0]") .setJustification(0) .setVisibility(data.getCustomer().getAddrLine2() != null || !data.getCustomer().getAddrLine2().isEmpty() ? PdfFormField.VISIBLE : PdfFormField.HIDDEN) .setValue(data.getCustomer().getAddrLine2() != null ? data.getCustomer().getAddrLine2() : "");`

but not able to move below sections of city, state, zip fields automatically. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What kind of form definition do your PDFs use? AcroForm (the genuine PDF form technology)? XFA (an XML form definition style deprecated in PDFs for 6 years now)? Hybrid? Something else? iText supports foremost AcroForm forms and to a certain degree static XFA forms. Furthermore, there is an iText addon to flatten dynamic XFA forms to AcroForm forms.

Comment: We use AcroForm for iText. And may I know what's the iText addon ?

Comment: *"We use AcroForm for iText"* - Ok, in that case you can in principle use iText for filling in.  As you found out yourself, though, JavaScript is not executed by iText during fill-in. Primarily because iText Core simply doesn't execute JavaScript but also because the events are designed for UI interactions and don't strictly correspond to programmatic fill-ins. *"And may I know what's the iText addon ?"* - there are numerous libraries built on top of iText Core by the people who provide iText, see [here](https://itextpdf.com/resources/downloads).

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned in my second part of the description. I used form field property setVisibility to hide the field, it works but again I am not able to move the below fields one step higher. That’s the main issue